# Typical latencies on unladen networks

Tags: networking, latency

I'd like to know typical round-trip times on networks in order to determine whether or not they will be the limiting factor in the latency of a whole application. Measuring it on a laden 100Mbps network here I get 95% of pings under 500µs with a median of 400µs.

What are typical latencies on unladen networks and how does the bandwidth spec (e.g. 1Gb, 10Gb) of the network affect the latency?

Comment: I'm not a network specialist but I would think this not only depends on the bandwidth, but also on the components between server and receiver (type/brand of routers, how many routers, ...).

Comment: @Patrick: I'd like a minima wrt the possible setups, e.g. two machines alone on a single switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 1gb hardware I see 80µs ICMP latency, I cannot help on 10GigE or InfiniBand.

At faster fabrics though it really depends upon what protocols you are using, TCP often has more acceleration options than other protocols and hence can reach higher performance figures.  Similarly it also depends upon what NIC and operating system and how the NICs are configured, whether you want lower latency or higher bandwidth.

Looking at 10GigE NICs you will find many have a TCP offload engine (ToE) which manages everything for you.  Without ToE you need to look at interrupt coalescing configuration, how long the OS will wait before pushing and pulling packets from the NIC.

Answer (score 0):

TCP / IP are the standard protocol used by all computers connected to the Internet so that they can communicate. Keep in mind that the Internet connected computers in many different classes and incompatible hardware and software are in many cases, at all the possible ways and means of connection.
[UDP Offoad in FPGA](http://intilop.com)